# Nested loops in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Fairly new to writing pipelines in Jenkins and can't seem to get past this particular issue.  I wish to take 2 static lists and have each of the second list item appended to the first.  Mostly I have succeeded in this but I don't seem to be able to find a method to remove the brackets from the second list item.  Ultimately I will be breaking out the compile part into a separate library.

Many thanks in advance to anyone that can assist.

My code:

```
def food = ["eggs","chips"]
def drink =["water","juice","cola"]
def meal = []

    for (String fd : food){
        [drink].transpose().each {drinks ->
            meal.add("Food: ${fd}, Drinks: ${drinks}")}
    }

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Results') {
            steps {
                echo 'Results'
                echo "${meal}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the results (truncated)

```
Results
[Pipeline] echo
[Food: eggs, Drinks: [water], Food: eggs, Drinks: [juice], Food: eggs, Drinks: [cola], Food: chips, Drinks: [water], Food: chips, Drinks: [juice], Food: chips, Drinks: [cola]]
[Pipeline] }
```

As you can see from the results I have what I need except for not being able to remove the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about instead of using transpose, use something simpler:

```
def meal = []
  food.each { item1 ->
    //println item1
    
    drink.each { item2 ->
      //println item2
      meal.add("Food: ${item1}, Drinks: ${item2}")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Glen, many thanks for the reply.  I sometimes wonder why I try and make things so complicated!  Perfect answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This would also have been a nice use case for `combinations()`:

```
def food  = ["eggs","chips"]
def drink = ["water","juice","cola"]
def meal  = [food, drink].combinations().collect { fd, drinks -> "Food: $fd, Drinks: $drinks" }
```